# bootstrap style sheet in cpanel not read in

Tags: css, cpanel

I use the following css for some icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

It works on my local drive but not when I upload the html files to cpanel.

Comment: Can you try opening up Chrome / Firefox Devtools and see if there are any warnings or errors?

Comment: Yes, it says: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you try changing the link above to use https and try?

Comment: I think it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you wrote, you were facing a Mixed Content warning from the browser and browsers block resources when they come from insecure servers.

Changing the CDN link to use `https`, as I mentioned in the comment, is one way to solve it.

More reading
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content